# Работа с файлами и удаление выбранных данных

Tags: python, файлы, данные

У меня в `logins.txt` к примеру есть 4 логина
`admin, user, helper, vip` пользователь выбирает, что ему нужно удалить например `vip`. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Прочитать весь файл. Показать пользователю. Удалить указанное. Сформировать новое содержимое. Полностью переписать файл (возможно, сохранив старый как .BAK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сперва открываем файл для чтения и записываем всё в список.
Затем открываем тот же файл, но на перезапись и записываем туда наш список, ранее удалив из него ненужную строку.

```
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != "nickname_to_delete":
            f.write(line)
```